# How to save in a variable a list of hosts from hostvars, except localhost

Tags: ansible

## What do I want

For example, I have a redis replication setup and apps on the same servers. I want to tell my apps that there are some hosts with the redis instances.

App reads the hosts from an `.env` file (it's also a template):

```
REDIS_URLS=rediscache://{{ redis_hosts|join(",") }}
```

I could describe the hosts in playbook like this:

```
  ...
  vars:
    redis_hosts:
      - 'redis1.exmaple.com:6379'
      - 'redis2.exmaple.com:6379'
  ...
```

but...

## What the Problem

1. I don't want to specify this hosts manually, since they are already known by Ansible (they are all `hostvars` keys).
2. I want to request `localhost` instead of public host name when a redis instance in the same server as an app.

So I thoght about something like this:

```
  ...
  vars:
    redis_hosts:
      - 'localhost:6379' # it's always here
      - '{{ item.key }}:6379'
      with_dict: hostvars
      when: item.key != inventory_hostname
  ...
```

but it doesn't work obviously.

Or I could to move the logic to the `.env` file:

```
REDIS_URLS=rediscache://{% for host in hostvars.keys() -%}
    {%- if inventory_hostname == host -%}
        localhost:6379
    {%- else -%}
        {{ host }}:6379
    {%- endif -%}
{%- if not loop.last -%},{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

but I also have a role, that requires the same list of hosts.

Comment: Move the logic to where you use this variable.

Comment: Yes, that is what I also tried. Actually this would work well for the .env file. But I also have a role, that uses the same list of hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop current node from list (as `inventory_hostname` for example) and replace it with `localhost`:

```
# msg is constructed from 'redis_hosts' variable
- debug:
    msg: "{{ redis_list | join(',') }}"
  vars:
    redis_list: "{{ ['localhost:6379'] + redis_hosts | reject('match',inventory_hostname) | list }}"
```

But it seems that you have a bit of copy-pasting: if you have redis hosts in your inventory, why do you have separate variable `redis_hosts` for that?

You can construct this list from your inventory group, let's assume it to be `redis`:

```
# msg is constructed from inventory group 'redis'
- debug:
    msg: "{{ redis_list | join(',') }}"
  vars:
    redis_nodes: "{{ ['localhost'] + groups['redis'] | difference([inventory_hostname]) }}"
    redis_port: 6379
    redis_list: "{{ redis_nodes | map('regex_replace','$',':'+redis_port|string) | list }}"
```

Comment: I don't have `redis_hosts` in my inventory, I use keys of `hostvars` dictionary for this.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Now I get it. The second solution works perfectly in my case.